# image based on a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

anyone here has any idea how to work with images in vba?,
I have this board filled with 0s and 1s and I want to insert a picture if the cell value is 1 , and keep it empty if not .. where do i start?
on another subject , I tried this code to make cells with 0 empty:

```
For i = 1 to n '(defined in the code)
    For j = 1 to n 
        If Cells(i, j).Value = 1 Then
            Cells(i, j).Value = ""
        End if
    Next j 
Next i
```

It didn't work... any thoughts?

Comment: Please ask one question per thread. That is because you can select only one answer.

Comment: Insert a picture from where?  Have you tried recording a macro while inserting a picture and positioning it over a cell?   You can't "insert" a picture in a cell - the best you can do is position it over the cell.

Answer (score 0):

To show zeroes as empty select File > Options > Advanced. Scroll down to "Display options for this worksheet" and remove the check mark against "Show a zero in cells that have zero value". This will apply to all cells in the worksheet for which it is set.

If you need to show zeroes in some cells and not in others, use the cell format. Click Format Cells > Number > Custom. Enter a custom format like `0;0;` Zero values will be hidden for the selected cell only.

How does this work? The cell format has, in fact, 4 formats, separated by semi-colons. The first is for positive numbers, the second for negative ones, the third for zeroes and the last for text. So, my example format has a zero for positive, zero for negative, nothing for zero and text undefined. With this format you won't be able to display dollars & cents because the cents are suppressed. You won't be able to differentiate positive from negative numbers because they are displayed identically. If you have such needs you can apply more suitable formats for positive and negative.

As an aside to the above that might be useful for what you are doing, a format like `1;1;;"1"` would display any number or any text you enter as 1 and show an empty cell for zero.